# Jackson Scala Module deserialization to map with custom type as value

Tags: scala, dictionary, jackson, deserialization

Does anyone knows why when im trying to deserialize JSon into Map[String,MyCustomType] i always get after deserialization Object of type Map[String, HashMap[String, String]]?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command you use for deserialize it to your type?

Comment: I use the one coming from RestAssured library, where it uses one of the deserializers (which in my case is configured for Jackson) and i use it like: body().as(classOf[Map[String, MyCustomClass]]). I also tried with TypeFactory and doing it 'manually' as shown in many examples for Jackson but i ended up getting the same result.

Comment: Why don't you use the `readValue` method? Like: `mapper.readValue(YOUR_JSON_STRING, classOf[Map[String, MyCustomType]])` ?

Comment: As I said in previous comment: I already tried all of the common ways to deserialize it and none of them worked as expected.